# Category page redirected to homepage or existing page on click in Laravel 8 project

Tags: php, laravel-8, digital-ocean

After migrating name.com hosting to digitalocean hosting. My project had some issues that need to solve earlier. One of main problem is all categories both front-end & back-end url redirected to existing page or homepage. But on my localhost server project working fine. After var_dump request on server, query_string get null. Whether dd() Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection orginal has the correct id. Please see codes ->

DD Request

```
#Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3783 ▼
  #items: array:19 [▼
    9 => App\SubCategory {#3793 ▼
      #original: array:8 [▼
        "id" => 17
      ]
```

Route

```
Route::get('browse/subcategory/', 'CategoriesController@subcategorypage')->name('subcategory.page');
```

Controller

```
public function subcategoryPage(Request $request){

$ipaddress = $request->getClientIp();

$geoip = geoip()->getLocation($ipaddress);
$usercountry = strtoupper($geoip->country);

$cats = SubCategory::where('id', $request->id)->first();

// dd($cats);

if (!$cats) {

  return redirect('/')->with('delete', '404 | category not found !');
}

if ($request->type) {

  $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', $request->type == 'paid' ? '1' : '0')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
} else if ($request->sortby) {

  if ($request->sortby == 'l-h') {


    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', '1')->orderBy('price', 'DESC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
  }

  if ($request->sortby == 'h-l') {


    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', '1')->orderBy('price', 'ASC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
  }

  if ($request->sortby == 'a-z') {

    if ($request->type) {
      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', $request->type == 'paid' ? 1 : 0)->orderBy('title', 'ASC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    } else {

      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->orderBy('title', 'ASC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    }
  }

  if ($request->sortby == 'z-a') {

    if ($request->type) {
      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', $request->type == 'paid' ? 1 : 0)->orderBy('title', 'DESC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    } else {

      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->orderBy('title', 'DESC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    }
  }

  if ($request->sortby == 'newest') {

    if ($request->type) {

      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', $request->type == 'paid' ? 1 : 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    } else {

      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    }
  }

  if ($request->sortby == 'featured') {

    if ($request->type) {
      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('type', '=', $request->type == 'paid' ? 1 : 0)->where('featured', '=', '1')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    } else {

      $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('featured', '=', '1')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
    }
  }
} else if ($request->limit) {

  // return 'ghjj';

  if ($request->limit == '10') {

    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate(2);
  } elseif ($request->limit == '30') {

    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate($request->limit);
  } elseif ($request->limit == '50') {

    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate($request->limit);
  } elseif ($request->limit == '100') {

    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate($request->limit);
  } else {

    $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
  }
} else if ($request->lang) {

  $lang = CourseLanguage::where('id', $request->lang)->first();

  $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->where('language_id', '=', $lang->id)->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
} else {

  $courses = $cats->courses()->where('status', '1')->paginate($request->limit ?? 10);
}

$filter_count = $courses->count();

$childcat = ChildCategory::where('subcategory_id', $cats->id)->get();

return view('front.category', compact('cats', 'courses', 'childcat', 'filter_count', 'usercountry'));
```

}

Comment: maybe there is an authentication problem?

Comment: do you have set authentication middleware?

Comment: There was server configuration related problem. Now, it's solved. thanks for you comment.